# Trying to create a view in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, view, laravel-blade

Here's what I want to do: A simple blade view with a form in it where I can post images to test an app function.

So, here's what I've done...

In resources/views/ImageControllerTest.blade.php:

```
<html>
<body>
{{Form::open(array('route'=>'image.store'))}}

{{Form::close()}}

</body>
</html>
```

In routes/web.php:

```
Route::get('/formtest', function () {
    return view('ImageControllerTest');
});
```

In my browser, I go to `http://localhost:8000/formtest` and I get this error:

```
FatalErrorException in ac777a228fac6b0e4c0e9981973de27c8907364b.php line 3:
Class 'Form' not found
in ac777a228fac6b0e4c0e9981973de27c8907364b.php line 3
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you need to use `{{Form..` then you should install [Form Helper](https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.2/html)

Answer (score 0):

the `Form` has been deprecated since Laravel 5, I believe. In order to continue using this syntax you'll have to download [this package](https://github.com/LaravelCollective/html)

Or just use plain html

```
<form action="/images" method="POST">
</form>
```

Comment: If I do that, the form doesn't show up. I just get an empty page

Comment: do what - the first option with package or the second option with plain html?

Comment: @AlmazikG http://www.relatably.com/m/img/why-not-both-meme-image/82733-why-not-both-meme-5LvD.jpeg

Answer (score 0):

The form is now an external package. You will have to include it via the composer.

```
composer require "laravelcollective/html":"^5.3.0"
```

Add to the provider's array

```
Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider::class,
```

Add to aliases array

```
'Form' => Collective\Html\FormFacade::class,
'Html' => Collective\Html\HtmlFacade::class,
```

Follow instructions here: https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.3/html